# Как устроен for в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

Если у меня есть `tuple = (44, 44 ,44 ,44)`

И я открываю `for` для этого кортежа например:

```
for item in tuple:
    pass

print(item)
```

а потом принтую `item`, почему у меня `output` ***44***, объясните пжл, почему `item = 44` в этом случае, если все элементы там равны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`output -> 44`, потому что последнее значение в кортеже равно `44`

Цикл `for` используется для перебора последовательности (то есть списка, кортежа, словаря, set или строки).

Это меньше похоже на ключевое слово `for` в других языках программирования и больше похоже на метод итератора, как в других объектно-ориентированных языках программирования.

С помощью цикла `for` мы можем выполнить набор операторов один раз для каждого элемента в списке, кортеже, set или строки.

```
_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4)

for item in _tuple:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Я не понял как связан последнее значение, тогда если поменять на tuple = (44, 44 ,44, 33) то output не будет же 33. Вопрос заключаеться в том почему когда все значение одинаковы он притует только один 44. Понимаю что он проходит через все значение, но не понимаю почему item = 44

Comment: Как раз будет 33. Дело в том, что `print` находится _за циклом_, т.е. выполняется только один раз после того, как цикл закончился и показывает только последнее значение из `tuple`.

Comment: @David  если говорить о синтаксисе в Python, это то, что отступы имеют значение: они определяют, какой код попадает в блок; когда блок кода начинается и заканчивается.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за ваш опыт ребят

Answer (score 5):

Если подробно разобрать код выше, то вот что ты делаешь:

```
Для каждого из элементов в tuple:
    pass (Ничего не делаем, пропускаем)

Напечатать(элемент)
```

Иначе говоря, цикл for проходит по всем значениям из `tuple`. От первого до последнего. И завершает свое выполнение.

Заметь, что после `for` значение `item = последнему элементу из tuple`

А дальше ты его выводишь через `print`.

Можешь поиграться с этим, чтобы понять лучше.

```
tuple = (11, 22 ,33 ,44)

for item in tuple:
    print("Я item, сейчас я равен = " + str(item))
    pass
print("Я последний из item, оставшийся после for, мое значение = " + str(item))
```

Вывод:

```
Я item, сейчас я равен = 11
Я item, сейчас я равен = 22
Я item, сейчас я равен = 33
Я item, сейчас я равен = 44
Я последний из item, оставшийся после for, мое значение = 44
```

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помог!